# vim key mapping being fired by carriage return

Tags: vim, keymapping

I use gvim on windows 10 and am trying to get a good keymap to open a vertical split to a new file. I first tried

```
nnoremap <c-m><c-m> :vnew<CR>
```

but for some reason if I hit carriage return twice in succession in normal mode, I would get a new vertical split window. So I took the trailing carriage return out of the key map

```
nnoremap <c-m><c-m> :vnew
```

and still get a new vertical split window if I hit carriage return three times in normal mode, which for some reason I find myself doing.

Why is carriage return setting off the key map when there isn't even a carriage return in the key map in _vimrc? I have restarted vim with no effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Vim's point of view, `<C-m>` is `<CR>` and `<CR>` is `<C-m>`.

They are *the same key* so you can't map something to `<C-m>` without mapping it to `<CR>` and vice-versa.

You'll need to find another key combo for your mapping.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the way that the keyboard input is handled internally, this unfortunately isn't generally possible today, even in GVIM. Some key combinations, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + non-alphabetic cannot be mapped, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + letter vs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + letter cannot be distinguished. (Unless your terminal sends a distinct *termcap* code for it, which most don't.) In insert or command-line mode, try typing the key combination. If nothing happens / is inserted, you cannot use that key combination. This also applies to `<Tab>` / `<C-I>`, `<CR>` / `<C-M>` / `<Esc>` / `<C-[>` etc. (Only exception is `<BS>` / `<C-H>`.) This is a known pain point, and the subject of various discussions on vim_dev and the #vim IRC channel.

Some people (foremost Paul LeoNerd Evans) want to fix that (even for console Vim in terminals that support this), and have floated various proposals, cp. http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/626e83fa4588b32a/bfbcb22f37a8a1f8

But as of today, no patches or volunteers have yet come forward, though many have expressed a desire to have this in a future Vim release.